# How to Respond to an event in Angular?

Tags: angular, typescript, events

I've an event that is emitted every 10 seconds.

On the receiving end, I've subscribed to it.

**Question:** How do I respond back to the event with some data to class that emits the event

```
constructor(@Inject(ABC.XYZ) private events: XYZEvents){

this.events.event1.subscribe(()=> {
  console.log("Event1")
  //Return some data here
})

}
```

Comment: Well I believe you would have to raise another event from this receiving end which need to be subscribed in the class emitting the event.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you can do is create a class variable in XYZEvents and make a function to update that variable, then call that function from inside the subscribe.

```
## The service class
class XYZEvets {
    ## classVariable definition

    updateVariable(value) {
        classvariable = value
    }
}
```

```
constructor(@Inject(ABC.XYZ) private events: XYZEvents){

this.events.event1.subscribe(()=> {
  console.log("Event1")
  //Return some data here
  this.events.updateVariable(data)
})

}
```